# Removing link tags and inner html from generated content

Tags: php

I have a block of text in a template file called by php 
**using the following code:**

```
echo $playlist->description
```

the field contains html links that I would like to remove when the results of that field are displayed as content within a tweetbox created using the twitter api.

**Example of displayed text:**

```
<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> some text here.
```

**I'm looking to achieve the following result:**

```
some text here
```

I've looked into accomplishing this with regex, `preg_replace`, and a few others. However, I have yet to figure out how to incorperate into my existing string.

**I've tried the following with no success,**

```
echo $playlist->description->$str = preg_replace('#(<a.*?>).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $str)
```

I am a self proclaimed php noob and I've spent a few weeks on trying to accomplish my objective, so any help is greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm real close! HELP!!! :)

Best Regards,
Mike

Comment: Show your templating code too, please.

Comment: Can I assume there should be a terminating `.` in your sample output text, as there is in the input?

Comment: @Madbreaks You are correct sir, please see my additional question on your provided solution. Thanks again for your help, your solution worked great!

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this without using regex !

```
$a = end(explode('</a>' , $playlist->description ));
```

this will give you everything that comes after `</a>`

Comment: Hmm, why is that better than a RegEx?

Comment: it's faster , simpler and easier to understand

Comment: Is it faster?  You're parsing the string, creating an array and then operating on it.  Two function calls.  Vs. one RegEx op?  I call BS!  Easier to understand? Without knowing the problem I would have a hard time looking at that line of code and understanding what it is doing. You're working on a string, use string tools.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('#.*?</a>\s*(.*)#', "$1", $playlist->description);
```

Cheers

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar!! Thank you so much, I have one more question. Do you know of an additional modification that would allow only twitter user names to be show and remove text like "n/a" and "blah blah blah" leaving "@username" to be displayed?

Comment: Also, I'd like to remove "(" and ")" if possible. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I made a function that removes the HTML tags along with their contents:

Function:

```
<?php
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) {

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags);
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]);

  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) {
    if($invert == FALSE) {
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
    else {
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
  }
  elseif($invert == FALSE) {
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
  }
  return $text;
}
?>
```

Sample text:
$text = '**sample** text with tags';

Result for strip_tags($text):
sample text with tags

Result for strip_tags_content($text):
text with

Result for strip_tags_content($text, '**'):
sample** text with

Result for strip_tags_content($text, '', TRUE);
text with tags

I hope that someone is useful :)